# Run my code on Ropsten network without using Infura

Tags: truffle, metamask, ropsten

As I understood, Infura is a remote node give us the ability to interact with the network if we do not want to download the full node in our machine.

If I understood that correctly, can I download the full Ropsten node in my machine and communicate with Ropsten network from my machine without using a intermediate like Infura

If yes, how I can connect to ropsten from truffle.js to deploy my smart contract on ropsten?

I did research and found that I can download the full node using:

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --cache=1048 --ropsten --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545 console
```

It will take time to sync the full node in my machine.

If that correct ? if yes, how can I fund the accounts to deploy the code ? can I use the MetaMAsk account ?

Thanks

Comment: are u going to use truffle ?

Comment: You can't find an account, you make an account and you transfer ether to it.. then u can use that account to sign transactions

Comment: yes I will use truffle, and how I can transfer ether to it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can run Ethereum node yourself on any network, there is no reason to use Infura.
2. Yes you can use MetaMask
3. You fund the accounts same way as you would fund them Infura, this question is not related to the node. Generally, you can get Ropsten testnet ETH from a Ropsten faucet (please Google).